# Multiple buttons used to JQuery slideToggle one div

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a series of buttons and a form on a webpage.

The form is hidden on page load and i'm using `slideToggle` to show the form when a button is pressed.

The html is like this:

```
<div id="links">
    <button id="btn_01" class="tog active">Open</button>
    <button id="btn_02" class="tog">Open</button>
    <button id="btn_03" class="tog">Open</button>
</div>

<div id="form">
  <button id="close">Close</button>
  <form>Form contents...</form>
</div>
```

and so far the JS i have (to fire from one button) is:

```
$("#form").hide();

$("button.tog").bind("click", function(){

    if($("button.active").length) $("button.active").removeClass("active");
    if($("#form").is(":visible") == true) { $("#form).slideUp();

    $(this).addClass('active');
    $("#form").slideToggle();
});

$("buttton#close").click( function {
    $('#form').slideUp();
});
```

when any button is clicked, if #form is open it should slideUp, and the active class should be removed from the old button and added on the one that's just been clicked.

there should also be the ability to click button#close from within #form to fire the slideToggle (and also remove the active class from the #links button.

i'm fairly new to JQuery and am having trouble with the order of the code.

when #form is open and the original button is clicked the `slideToggle` function closes then re-opens the div.

i've tried lots of variations of this but can't get it to work properly.

any help would be much appreciated.

cheers, Leon

JSFiddle mockup: http://jsfiddle.net/leonharris/9mKTc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $frm = $('#form').hide();

    var $bts = $("button.tog").on('click', function () {
        var $this = $(this)
        $bts.filter(".active").not(this).removeClass('active');
        $this.toggleClass('active');

        if ($this.hasClass('active') && $frm.is(':visible')) {
            $frm.stop(true, true).slideUp(function () {
                $(this).slideDown()
            });
        } else {
            $frm.stop(true, true).slideToggle();
        }
    });
    $bts.filter('.active').click();

    $("#close").click(function () {
        $bts.filter(".active").removeClass('active');
        $frm.slideUp();
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Th3FV/)

Comment: thanks Arun, it's heading in the right direction.

a few questions though:

there's a slight problem. if a button is active then i click on another button, #form closes but the new button get's the class active.

when another button is clicked #form should close then re-open (to simulate a new form) and the .active class should shift to the current button.

Comment: and can it be hidden on page load?

Comment: @user2843317 it can be... but I displayed it because there is a button with active class

Comment: so i just remove the active class to start with?

Comment: wow. thats amazing - thanks so much for the help. does exactly what i wanted.

Comment: sorry, one more thing: can the 'Open' button text be changed to 'Close' when button has .active class?